Why am I getting conflicting dependencies from the requirements file when deploying mwaa?
I'm deploying MWAA with Airflow version 2.10.1 on a non-public network, with the following requirements file:
--find-links /usr/local/airflow/plugins
--no-index

pyarrow==14.0.2
filelock==3.15.4
platformdirs==4.2.2
pydantic==2.8.2
virtualenv==20.26.3
distlib==0.3.8
snowflake-connector-python==3.12.1
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.6.1
astronomer-cosmos==1.7.1
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==5.7.0

I recognize that its standard to include a constraints file, but since I'm on a private network, it wouldn't find the standard constraints file anyway. I get the following error in the log file:
WARNING: Constraints should be specified for requirements.txt. Please see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/working-dags-dependencies.html#working-dags-dependencies-test-create

Forcing local constraints
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in links: /usr/local/airflow/plugins
ERROR: Cannot install pyarrow==14.0.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
The conflict is caused by:
The user requested pyarrow==14.0.2
The user requested (constraint) pyarrow==14.0.2
To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip to attempt to solve the dependency conflict

This works fine when I deploy locally using the same plugins folder with aws-mwaa-local-runner, but doesn't work when I deploy on AWS. Additionally, I don't have anything in my startup.sh file.
The following is what's in the plugins file for pyarrow:
pyarrow-14.0.2-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl
Any ideas?

I think this might be a python version issue? I think this issue would occur if I had downloaded packages from a different version of python. According to this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/mwaa-faqs.html 3.11 should be the right python version for 2.10.1, but I can't think of anything else that would cause this error.

You can place constraints.txt in the root of your deployment package, most likely the same level as requirements.txt.
Update requirements.txt to reference this local path directly as following:
--find-links /usr/local/airflow/plugins
--no-index
-c constraints.txt

pyarrow==14.0.2
filelock==3.15.4
platformdirs==4.2.2
pydantic==2.8.2
virtualenv==20.26.3
distlib==0.3.8
snowflake-connector-python==3.12.1
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.6.1
astronomer-cosmos==1.7.1
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==5.7.0

This approach should ensure that pip finds constraints.txt when installing packages in MWAA.
Re deploy the updated zip file and check the logs for further issues.

Starting with Apache Airflow v2.7.2, the requirements.txt file must include a --constraint statement. Amazon MWAA enforces this to ensure compatibility between the packages in your requirements file and the specific version of Apache Airflow you’re using.
If you don’t provide a custom constraints file, MWAA will apply a default constraint file to avoid version conflicts. However, since you’re on a private network without access to the standard constraint file, you could create a local constraints file and reference it directly in your requirements.txt file with:
--constraint /usr/local/airflow/plugins/custom-constraints.txt

For more details, refer to the MWAA documentation

This didn't work - I added the constraints file from the documentation for Airflow 2.10.1 and python 3.11, but I couldn't find the file in the plugins folder, which just threw another error.

did you add a constraints file to the plugin.zip?

Yes, I copied the content from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.10.1/constraints-3.11.txt, added it to constraints.txt in the plugins folder, and added the header
--constraint /usr/local/airflow/plugins/constraints.txt
It wasn't able to find the constraint file, with the following error: ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/airflow/plugins/constraints.txt'
I'm not sure its getting unpacked from the uploaded zip correctly?
